# Regular expression for strings where one letter is odd, while only having exactly 1 other letter

Tags: regex, expression

I've seen a lot of posts about odd and even letters but nothing about odd or even letters while having exactly one other letter. How would I solve for this? all strings that contain an odd number of a's and exactly one b. the set is {a,b}

Comment: My guess is the answer would be something like this. (b)ab*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`^((b(a(aa)*))|((a(aa)*)b)|(aa)*b(a(aa)*)|((a(aa)*)b(aa)*))$`

Above is my regular expression. There might be a prettier way to do it, but this is the simplest to understand.

Break it down piece by piece and find out in which cases this expression should be true. There are 4 cases where the expression can be true.

- `(b(a(aa)*))` b then odd amount of a's
- `((a(aa)*)b)` odd amount of a's then there is b
- `(aa)*b(a(aa)*)` even amount of a's, b, odd amount of a's
- `((a(aa)*)b(aa)*)` odd amount of a's, b, even amount of a's

It helps to realize that `even + odd = another odd number`.

Comment: I thought the first regular expression was the answer lol. Thank you for sharing, I'm sure this breakdown will help a lot of people.

Comment: Great! Glad i could help. If this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark.